# Traefik with docker swarm and mode: global: frontend rule to substitute hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a Docker Swarm cluster (currently 5 machines) where I run everything as a Docker Stack like so, initiating from the host: manager1:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

But I use Traefik as reverse proxy.
I wanted to add a Syncthing container to share some data between nodes, so I want it to run on each node. This is achieved thanks to the option:

```
deploy:
  mode: global
```

This properly creates the containers I want, one per node.

I then want to access each Syncthing instance, thanks to Traefik, with unique urls like this:

frontend: manager1.syncthing.mydomain.com    -->  backend: syncthing container on host manager1
frontend: worker1.syncthing.mydomain.com    -->  backend: syncthing container on host worker1
frontend: worker2.syncthing.mydomain.com    -->  backend: syncthing container on host worker2
...

I fail to find the proper configuration for this (it is even possible?).

I thought about substituting variable in the docker-compose like so:

```
deploy:
  ...
  labels:
  ...
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${HOSTNAME}.syncthing.mydomain.com"
```

Even if $HOSTNAME is defined on all nodes (including manager), this fails; Traefik creates a useless route: ".syncthing.mydomain.com". A few researches have shown that this should at least not substitute ${HOSTNAME} for "" ([pull/30781](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/30781)) but for "manager1". Anyway, I think this can be safely expected not to work as the substitution would probably be done on the master1 node where the `docker stack deploy` command is run.

As a workaround, I can deploy one service per node and use placement constraints to deploy one service per node; but this does not scale as new nodes would have to be added manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS:
I run everything as arm on raspberry pi.

- Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
- docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
- traefik:cancoillotte

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48906127/how-to-assign-different-port-to-container-replicas-in-docker-swarm/48919038#48919038

Comment: Thanks, I understand it is a little bit away from the swarm way of thinking but I still find writing down one service per node "non-ideal or hackish". Especially since it doesn't scale automatically!  Maybe I can write a script that updates the docker-compose as new nodes are added; still...

Comment: @Alex did you manage to find a way around this?